# How to use TypeScript Map Object on Form in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary

First of all, I apologize for my bad English. :)

I'm trying to do a project with Angular. I have an object named Item and I have a Map object inside it. Example Item object is as follows;

```
item: {
 name: string,
 description: string,
 values: Map<string, number>
}
```

I want to create a form with ngModel about this object. I want to create an input equal to the size of the Values object and enter the values in the Values object from these inputs.

Do you think this is possible? How can I do it if possible?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Code Example:
[Stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkud9m)

Comment: Can you post any code with something you've tried? I'm a bit confused about what you want to do with the Map object. Do you want a individual input field for each property within the Map?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Comment: @thenolin I have a Value list. But this list is not a fixed list. A list that is constantly changing and unclear. With this list, I will fill in the key property of the Values (Map object) ​​in the Item object and ask the user to fill in the value property of this list. So the more values ​​in the Value list, the more inputs I have to create. I hope I described it :)

Comment: @nircraft Thank you for welcoming me. I edited my question and shared a code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a form array, which each contains a group of key and value.

```
group {
  name,
  description,
  array [
   group {
     key,
     value,
   },
   group {
     key,
     value,
   }
  ]
}
```

You will be able to push more groups to the array as needed. When submitting you iterate this array and extend the map.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to do this with the model and not with the form array? I've shared a code sample.